# Preventing a user from uninstalling the application based on registry search

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

I have created 3 independent MSI files using WIX3.8

The first MSI package is the core package which installs the basic(Core) components.

The other two MSI packages are add on to the first MSI. I have put the necessary checks in place which will prevent a user from installing the add-ons if the basic components are not installed.

The problem now is how do I prevent the user from un-installing the core components when the add-ons are installed?

I have added specific registry keys while installing each MSI so that I can refer them.

I have spent over 2 days on Google and SO but could not find any solution :(. If I missed anything please provide me the reference link.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Upgrade element with the other addon components upgrade codes to detect the other products.

E.G. In your core components installer add something like

```
<Upgrade Id ="Addon Product A's Upgrade GUID">
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Minimum="0.0.0.0" Property="ADDONADETECTED" IncludeMinimum="no" />
</Upgrade>

<Upgrade Id ="Addon Product B's Upgrade GUID">
 <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Minimum="0.0.0.0" Property="ADDONBDETECTED" IncludeMinimum="no" />
</Upgrade>

<Condition Message="There are other products that depend on these components, aborting uninstall.">
  <![CDATA[ADDONADETECTED OR ADDONBDETECTED AND (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: I am getting the above `Condition` `Message` when I try to install the core modules.

Comment: perhaps changing ADDONADETECTED OR ADDONBDETECTED to (ADDONADETECTED OR ADDONBDETECTED). Executing the msi from the commandline to generate a log file would be helpful so that you can see what the values of the properties are, the issue is in the condition, unfortunately I can't currently test the code.

Comment: I will check the suggestion and will post on Monday

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Add ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT to those MSI files so they don't show in Programs&Features.
2. Assuming you allow normal major upgrades, make the bundle do the uninstall with a command line parameter such as BUNDLEUNINSTALL=1 and then have a type 19 custom action that prevents the uninstall from continuing if REMOVE="ALL" AND BUNDLEUNINSTALL<>1.
3. I'm not sure that a registry search provides a good solution. I would use a custom action based on MsiEnumRelatedProducts (upgradecode of other products using these components) to find the ProductCodes of those products. If you get some ProductCodes back then you can call a type 19 custom action to prevent the uninstall.  In general Rick's suggestion is good, but I think the strategy you should go for is to use a bundle. This kind of thing: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/dependency/provides.html

Comment: The Add-ons are not mandatory to be installed. So I should provide the user an option to uninstall just the add-ons. So I can't hide them from program features which means the second suggestion also does not seem to fit with my problem :(

Comment: I was assuming you were using a WiX bundle because I think that would provide a solution.

Comment: I can't use the `Bundle` as there are some licensing issues which forced me to create independent msi packages. If `RegistrySearch` is a bad idea what do you suggest? I have an option for `FileSearch` and `DirectorySearch` also.